# Ruby 1.9.2 keeps reverting back to 1.8.7 after installing it using RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I installed Ruby 1.9.2. I used `rvm use 1.9.2` and then when I type `ruby -v` it says 1.9.2. Then when I quit terminal and reopen it, it says 1.8.7 again.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your default ruby is most likely not set to ruby 1.9.2. Try:

```
rvm --default use 1.9.2
```

Also if you want to see all ruby versions installed, you can run 'rvm list'. The default ruby is prefixed with a => symbol, as shown below.

```
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-1.9.1-p243 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-1.9.2-p136 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.2-p180 [ x86_64 ]
```

Comment: Yes, that worked...but I think that some stuff is still looking in 1.8...hence:


MacBook-Air: beatjunkie84$ rails server
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:926:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem rails (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:244:in `activate_dep'
 from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:236:in `activate'
 from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:1307:in `gem'
 from /usr/bin/rails:18

Comment: I don't think this is related. I believe you are running ruby 1.9.2 (assuming you ran the above command). Did you install rails? In your Gemfile, you'll need to add gem 'rails', then run 'bundle install', then try starting your server again.

Answer (score 2):

Once you switch over using `rvm --default use 1.9.2`, be sure to check your gem list. Once you switch over, your gem list will be almost empty.

Additionally, you can check to see more information regarding what version of ruby and gemset you're using with the command `rvm info`.

If it is in fact empty, simply install rails with the command `gem install rails`. Be sure to not use sudo with this command.