# Installing Ruby on Mac OS X 10.7

Tags: ruby, rvm, osx-lion, macos

I installed rvm and then ruby 1.9.2 but every time I close my terminal and reopen it, it shows me that rvm is not installed(zsh: correct 'rvm' to 'rvim' [nyae]?) and even ruby 1.9.2 can't be seen when I do ruby -v(ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]).

I did set the 1.9.2 version as the default one and used http://eddorre.com/posts/rails-ultimate-install-guide-on-os-x-lion-using-rvm-homebrew-and-pow as the guide for installation. I have Mac OS X 10.7. What am I doing wrong? I am doing what [Ruby 1.9.2 keeps reverting back to 1.8.7 after installing it using RVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876764/ruby-1-9-2-keeps-reverting-back-to-1-8-7-after-installing-it-using-rvm) says.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add this line to the bottom of your `.zshrc` file:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # This loads RVM into a shell session.
```

Comment: Does that mean I will have to change my shell by this command? chsh -s /bin/zsh
Changing shell for Richa.
Password for Richa: 
chsh: no changes made

Comment: If you followed that guide, you should already be on zsh (and since the error is "zsh: correct 'rvm'....", you are on zsh).  SO if you add that line to .zshrc, RVM should work.

Comment: I did this: Upgrade of RVM in /Users/richa/.rvm/ is complete.
//lot of text
Thank you for using RVM!

  ~Wayne

➜  ~  [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" then closed the window and restarted the terminal. On typing this Last login: Thu Sep  1 12:24:42 on ttys000
➜  ~  rvm pkg install iconv
zsh: correct 'rvm' to 'rvim' [nyae]? 
I again get the error.

Comment: No, there is a file called `.zshrc` which you must edit and put that line in; you don't just type it into the terminal. Putting in that file will tell zsh to load RVM every time you start a new terminal session.

Answer (score 0):

For more information about the .zshrc file - it's located in:

```
/Users/yourname/.zshrc
```