# Why does Ruby or RVM seem stuck at 1.8.7 on Linux Mint?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I am on Linux Mint 12.

I installed RVM and ran these commands:

```
rvm 1.9.2

rvm --default use 1.9.2
```

but `ruby -v` still outputs `ruby 1.8.7`.

`sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.2` returns saying 1.9.1 is the latest version.

How do I get Ruby to be running on 1.9.2?

When I run `rvm list` like suggested at "[Ruby 1.9.2 keeps reverting back to 1.8.7 after installing it using RVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876764/ruby-1-9-2-keeps-reverting-back-to-1-8-7-after-installing-it-using-rvm)", it outputs:

```
rvm rubies

   ruby-1.8.7-p352 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ x86_64 ]
```

So I think I must have a configuration issue.  My OS seems to be defaulting to the wrong version of Ruby.

I ran:

```
sudo apt-get remove ruby
```

But had no change.

Comment: What's your path show after running `rvm use 1.9.2-p290`?

Comment: what is the output of `rvm do ruby -v`?

Comment: @DaveNewton  Using /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290

Comment: @CarlZulauf The output is:                                            WARN: `rvm do ruby '-v'` is deprecated, use `rvm all do ruby '-v'` or `rvm 1.9.2 do ruby '-v'` instead.
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: @ChickenFur Did you install under sudo or something? Is that your entire path?!

Comment: @DaveNewton I think I installed under sudo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add string `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` into `~/.bashrc`? First, show your `echo $PATH` output. If this looks like (rvm paths before system paths):

```
/home/ayunin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11
```

Then you ran into the `magick`. Restart your terminal, and show ruby version. If does not work - you can launch `rvm implode` and reinstall all, yes.

Comment: rvm all do ruby -v  Seems to work. It returns ruby 1.9.2p290  But just doing ruby -v returns the 1.8.7 version.  My path variable doesn't have the .rvm folder in it.  I will try adding that.

Comment: I don't have a .rvm directory in my home directory to add to the path.   Should I?

Comment: Because I installed it using sudo it was all put in /usr/local/rvm so I added [[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function'   to my .bashrc file  now echoing the path shows /usr/share/ruby-rvm/bin as part of the path variable

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Linux Mint 12 has ruby-rvm already installed (at least on my machine) so could this be a problem?

you can stick with that but then I think you will need to add your username to the rvm group with `usermod -a -G username rvm`.

I removed removed `ruby-rvm` completely (with apt-get) and then followed the installation instructions from https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/ for 'single user' thus all my rvm files are located in ~/.rvm/bin/rvm
I added the line for rvm in my .bashrc and tested with 1type rvm | head -1`.

After that `rvm install 1.9.2` just worked and I installed it into `~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2`

After that `rvm use --default 1.9.2` set all up correctly.