# Properly installing Ruby and Rubygems on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

It seems this process is far harder than it should be.

Currently, I have ruby 1.9.2 installed manually. I wanted to update this to use RVM. So I installed that successfully, and then installed 1.9.3-p0, which is in my RVM directory under /zenph/.rvm

I upgraded rubygems using http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3

And my environment shows:

```
rvm 1.10.0  
ruby 1.9.3p0  
gem 1.8.12
```

So, why does "gem environment" show:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.12
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2010-08-18 patchlevel 0) [i686-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - /home/zenph/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Hmmm, problem in $PATH? See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569022/why-does-ruby-or-rvm-seem-stuck-at-1-8-7-on-linux-mint/8573936#8573936 If does not work, show your echo $PATH :-)

Comment: Have you done `rvm --default use 1.9.3` ?

Comment: Thanks steenslag, that fixed it! Thank you too avy for the answer. it did have something to do with my $PATH as well.

Comment: @steenslag Can you post your comment as an answer, with a small description ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see which Ruby is the default one, open a terminal and use:

```
rvm list default
```

To specify a Ruby to be the default , open a terminal and use:

```
rvm --default use 1.9.3
```

[Docs](https://rvm.io/rubies/default/)